# How to change the default timezone in Amazon Redshift?

Tags: sql, amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift

Setting a timestamp column to SYSDATE by default, stores it as **UTC**. Is it possible to change the timezone so SYSDATE stores dates and times to a different timezone?

So far, I've checked the [SET](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_SET.html) command but I'm not sure if it is possible to use it to change the timezone.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Basically, the answer is no. According to the [documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_Datetime_types.html):

> TIMESTAMP values are UTC, not local time, in both user tables and
>   Amazon Redshift system tables.
>
> Note Timestamps with time zones are not supported.

If you need the queries to return data in different timezone, you can use the [CONVERT_TIMEZONE](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/CONVERT_TIMEZONE.html) function, with either constant timezone value (or query parameter), or joining the result to a configuration table which contains the required timezone.

Comment: Thanks for your input. I opted to set the default value to my local timezone:
create_timestamp  timestamp DEFAULT convert_timezone('America/Toronto', getdate()) NOT NULL,

Comment: Just for clarification, timestamps with timezone information are supported, you can use the type TIMESTAMPTZ instead of TIMESTAMP. This is essentially and alias with timezone information.

Please refer to the documentation here - https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_Datetime_types.html#r_Datetime_types-timestamptz

Comment: Except that the `SET TIMEZONE = 'America/Los_Angeles';` for example that they specify using only sets the environment on the leader node and not the compute nodes that write the tables: so the table routinely gets UTC stamps. Either set User timezone or use Jorge's comment above. Same issue for Setting Random seeds.