# How do you convert timestamp with GMT timezone in Redshift?

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

How do you convert a string with DOW and GMT information to timestamptz in Redshift?

Example: `Mon Apr 01 2019 14:08:20 GMT-0400 (EDT)`

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36338266/how-to-change-the-default-timezone-in-amazon-redshift and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62193838/redshift-timestamp-timezone

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Amazon Redshift is based on PostgreSQL](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/c_redshift-and-postgres-sql.html). Therefore, with the use of [TO_DATE](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_TO_DATE_function.html) function, along with timezone related clauses, we could try the following.

```
SELECT 
  TO_TIMESTAMP('Mon Apr 01 2019 14:08:20 GMT-0400 (EDT)', 'XXX Mon DD YYYY HH:MI:SS')
  AT TIME ZONE REGEXP_REPLACE('Mon Apr 01 2019 14:08:20 GMT-0400 (EDT)', '^.*(...).$', '\\1');
```

This results in the following.

[image]

Unfortunately, it doesn't seem like we can do this conversion in one go because [time zone related format flags are valid for `TIMESTAMPTZ` only](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_FORMAT_strings.html).